Sending message error 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
I encounter this problem while running my discord bot on Pylex(A bot hosting service) I dont know why this error arise since the code run perfectly fine on my pc
This is what displayed on my bot's log on pylex:
{'title': 'Dr. STONE', 'alt_title': 'Dr. STONE', 'url': 'https://anilist.co/anime/105333', 'image_url': 'https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/medium/bx105333-02NGkx1vey2C.jpg', 'avrScore': 81, 'tags': [{'name': 'Post-Apocalyptic'}, {'name': 'Survival'}, {'name': 'Lost Civilization'}, {'name': 'Educational'}, {'name': 'Time Skip'}, {'name': 'Male Protagonist'}, {'name': 'Shounen'}, {'name': 'Environmental'}, {'name': 'Ensemble Cast'}, {'name': 'Primarily Teen Cast'}, {'name': 'Spearplay'}, {'name': 'Primarily Male Cast'}, {'name': 'Found Family'}, {'name': 'Kingdom Management'}, {'name': 'Asexual'}, {'name': 'Espionage'}, {'name': 'Tomboy'}], 'startDate': {'year': 2019, 'month': 7, 'day': 5}, 'endDate': {'year': 2019, 'month': 12, 'day': 13}}

API call sucessfully done!

There's an error while sending message 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

An error message was sent to fg27 

here's my code for getting info about a random anime
@app_commands.command(name="random_anime", description="goi y 1 anime ngau nhieu")
    async def get_anime(self, interaction: Interaction):
        try:
            anime_info = await self.get_random_anime(interaction)
            tags_list = ""
            print(anime_info)
            embeded_msg = discord.Embed(title="ANIME NGAU NHIEN", description="Hay xem va neu cam nhan",
                                        color=discord.Color.blue())
            embeded_msg.set_author(name=f"{interaction.user.name} muon xem anime", icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)
            embeded_msg.set_thumbnail(url=interaction.guild.icon)
            embeded_msg.set_image(url=anime_info['image_url'])
            embeded_msg.add_field(name=f"Title: {anime_info['title']}", value="", inline=False)
            alt_title = anime_info['alt_title']
            embeded_msg.add_field(name="", value=f"**Alternative Title**: {alt_title}", inline=False)
            embeded_msg.add_field(name="", value=f"**Average Score**: {anime_info['avrScore']}", inline=False)
            # description_clean = anime_info['description'].replace("<br><br>", "\n").replace("<i>", "**").replace("<br>", "")
            # embeded_msg.add_field(name = "",value= f"**Description**: {description_clean}", inline = False)
            embeded_msg.add_field(name="",
                                  value=f"**Start Date**: {anime_info['startDate']['day']}/{anime_info['startDate']['month']}/{anime_info['startDate']['year']}",
                                  inline=False)
            endDate = "Ongoing" if not anime_info['endDate'][
                'year'] else f"{anime_info['endDate']['day']}/{anime_info['endDate']['month']}/{anime_info['endDate']['year']}"
            embeded_msg.add_field(name="", value=f"**End Date**: {endDate}", inline=False)

            i = 0
            for tag in anime_info['tags']:
                if i == 5: break
                current_tag = f"`{tag['name']}`"
                tags_list += current_tag + " "
                i += 1
            embeded_msg.add_field(name="", value=f"**Tags**: {tags_list}", inline=False)

            if anime_info:
                print("API call sucessfully done!")

            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embeded_msg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"There's an error while sending message {e}")
            print(f"An error message was sent to {interaction.user.name} ")
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"There is an error sending the message", ephemeral=True)


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thanks for the comment, I have found a way, it is to defer the interaction.
